# Where can we download symbols for Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windbg, symbols

I am trying to debug a managed core dump, but it is hopeless, because the microsoft symbol server does not seem to contain the symbols for clr.dll version 4.6.1055.0.

Please, observe:

```
0:022> lmvm clr
Browse full module list
start    end        module name
73fa0000 74651000   clr        (export symbols)       clr.dll
    Loaded symbol image file: clr.dll
    Image path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
    Image name: clr.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Thu Nov  5 21:24:51 2015 (563C0F73)
    CheckSum:         006B3E43
    ImageSize:        006B1000
    File version:     4.6.1055.0
    Product version:  4.0.30319.0
    File flags:       8 (Mask 3F) Private
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® .NET Framework
    InternalName:     clr.dll
    OriginalFilename: clr.dll
    ProductVersion:   4.6.1055.0
    FileVersion:      4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    PrivateBuild:     DDBLD400
    FileDescription:  Microsoft .NET Runtime Common Language Runtime - WorkStation
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
    Comments:         Flavor=Retail
0:022> .reload /f clr.dll
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0xDA
         e:\symbols
         clr.pdb
         1C6AD585F62042AEB690C4C105CB9B962
SYMSRV:  e:\symbols\clr.pdb\1C6AD585F62042AEB690C4C105CB9B962\clr.pdb - file not found
SYMSRV:  e:\symbols\clr.pdb\1C6AD585F62042AEB690C4C105CB9B962\clr.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0xDB
         http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         clr.pdb
         1C6AD585F62042AEB690C4C105CB9B962
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/clr.pdb/1C6AD585F62042AEB690C4C105CB9B962/clr.pdb
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 404 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/clr.pdb/1C6AD585F62042AEB690C4C105CB9B962/clr.pd_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 404 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/clr.pdb/1C6AD585F62042AEB690C4C105CB9B962/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 404 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\clr.pdb\1C6AD585F62042AEB690C4C105CB9B962\clr.pdb - file not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/clr.pdb/1C6AD585F62042AEB690C4C105CB9B962/clr.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\clr.pdb\1C6AD585F62042AEB690C4C105CB9B962\clr.pdb not found
DBGHELP: clr.pdb - file not found
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for clr.dll - 
DBGHELP: clr - export symbols

************* Symbol Loading Error Summary **************
Module name            Error
clr                    PDB not found : cache*e:\symbols
                Unable to locate the .pdb file in this location

                       The system cannot find the file specified : srv*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                The SYMSRV client failed to find a file in the UNC store, or there
                is an invalid UNC store (an invalid path or the pingme.txt file is
                not present in the root directory), or the file is present in the
                symbol server exclusion list.
```

So, I went to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/download-symbols in hope to download the right symbols. But how do I know which one to download? I did download and installed the ones for Windows 10, x86 32-bit retail symbols of **Windows 10 - September 2016** and **Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 - August 2016**

But none contained the clr.pdb matching the GUID 1C6AD585F62042AEB690C4C105CB9B962.

What should I do? I am sure there is a better way that downloading and installing all of them.

Comment: On the page you linked to there are symbols for Windows 8 (and 8.1 if that is what you meant).

Comment: Yup and the download links are dead :-).

Comment: I guess they *really* wanted to kill 8. I suppose the computer in question would have been updated to 8.1 if that had been a desired option.

Answer (score 1):

The web archive has a [copy of the desired page from 2016-07-30](https://web.archive.org/web/20160730104526/https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/download-symbols) where the files seem to be available for download.

If version 4.6.1055.0 of .NET 4.6 was part of the OS at the time it was released, chances are that your clr.pdb is included. I still wonder why it's not available via the official symbol server, but it has happened before that Microsoft simply "forgot" to put it there.

Comment: Hmm, strange thing. I have deleted my entire symbols cache directory and now windbg is able to download the right symbols. Go figure...

Comment: 4.6.1055.0 is .net 4.6 and such PDBs are not part of any MSI. The symbol server from MS has (perf) issues over the last 2 months, so sometimes you have to try it several times.